# In Openlayers why is setUrl only available for tile vectors

Tags: openlayers

Why is setUrl available for tile layers but not for vector layers?

There is a setUrl function in ol/source/WMTS.js, ol/source/UrlTile.js, which is then imported into ol/source/VectorTile.js, and ol/source/ImageWMS.js, but nothing in ol/source/Vector.js? What do you do if you need to change the URL for a vector layer?

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 1):

The `url` option in `ol.source.Vector` can be a function:

```
var myUrl;
myUrlFunction = function() {
  return myUrl;
}

source = new ol.source.Vecor({
  url: myUrlFunction,
})
```

So you can set `myUrl` as required.